# Unable to install pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, macos-mojave

I am new to Mac OS. I am using it using a Macincloud managed server. In my Xcode project path using terminal I first ran `pod init` then I updated my pod file to

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SadhanaTracker' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'


  target 'SadhanaTrackerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'SadhanaTrackerUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

After that I ran `pod install` but it is not installing. The error I am receiving is shown below.

```
Analyzing dependencies
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libffi.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libffi.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

I followed the same steps on Mac Catalina and it worked but as Catalina didn't allowed sound using Managed serve I downgraded to Mojave. Can you please help me how to remove this error and install my dependencies successfully?

**Update-1**:Mac In cloud support gave me a way to install a gem using `gem install <gem-name> --user-install` . I ran this command from `ffi` gem and after that I got the below error message.

```
Analyzing dependencies
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc
  Referenced from: /Users/user197132/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libffi.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc
  Referenced from: /Users/user197132/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
```

I can observe that the location from which `ffi` gem is being referenced is changed but it is still expected in `/usr/lib/`.

Comment: Can you share which commands are you using for pod install?

Comment: @VinayakBhor I didn't understand your question. I just typed `pod install` in the terminal at the path of my Xcode project and I received the error shown above in the question. Before `pod install` I ran `pod init` and then edited my pod file to as shown above in question. If you are trying to know which pod's I am trying to install they are also mentioned above in the question.

Comment: Steps to install pod file:
1. Open terminal
2. Command on terminal: sudo gem install cocoapods
3. Set your project path on terminal. 
      Eg. cd <Project Path>  //get path on terminal drag project folder and drop   on terminal
  4.command : pod init
  5.go to pod file of your project and adding pod which you want to install
  6.added in pod file : pod ‘<Pod Name>’
  7.Command : Pod install
  8.Close project of Xcode
  9.open your Project from terminals
 10.Command : open <Project Name>.xcworkspace

Comment: @VinayakBhor I don't have sudo access in Managed server plan but cocoa pods are already installed I am encountering some other problem which you can know by reading the error message above.